# Windows Authentication in AngularJS project

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I have an angularjs project consisting of aspx (containing pure html), controllers in js and asmx web service calls to populate data in ng-grid.

I would now like to have certain buttons/functionalities hidden to an active directory users group.

Someone in other forum has suggested to use http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs but this has the controller in C#.

My controller looks something like this

```
 function () {
"use strict";
var app = angular.module('CPFWeb', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '../Default.aspx'
        })
```

....

Can you please suggest me bare bone code to include windows authentication in this project?

Thanks!

Comment: Authentication is a **server-side concern**. You can't enforce anything on the client - you may fake it, eg by limiting what you display or call, but you can't prevent anyone from checking your Javascript code or using the browser's network capture tool to find and subsequently use data or HTTP calls. Your *server-side code* should only send/display to the client the UI/data that the end user is allowed to view

Comment: Ok. So is there anyway I can get the active directory id of the user accessing this angular project?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET on the server side? Regardless, the answer is yes. So go try to implement getting the AD info you want on the server and then passing it to the client. If you get stuck on a specific part, that would be a more appropriate question.

Comment: Are you asking whether you can escape the browser's sandbox to get at OS-specific information? Besides, what would prevent someone from passing a *fake* ID to your code?

Comment: @mason that wouldn't be secure - security trimming should happen on the server, not the client. Even if it's only to show/hide non-critical elements, it's better to send a list of permitted elements to the browser, instead of having the browser code decide what to show/hide based on group membership. It's even possible to bind to such permission objects. It also makes it **a lot** easier to change the authentication mechanism when required

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't say security checks shouldn't be performed at the server side. But if you're writing a SPA or SPA-hybrid and want to display the appropriate UI for the level of access that the user has, then you need a way of getting this information to the client side, where the UI logic lives.